# Как с помощью регулярного выражения вернуть только нужные значения?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Имеется список *list1*:

```
list1 = [
          'Bank Asya 1. Lig 2004/2005',
          'Bank Asya 1. Lig 2006/2007', 
          'Bank Asya 1. Lig 2008',
          'Bank Asya 1. Lig 2009',
          'PTT 1. Lig 2012/2013',
          'PTT 1. Lig 2014',
          'PTT 1. Lig 2015'
        ]
```

Необходимо убрать ***ТОЛЬКО*** дату в конце, чтобы было так:

```
list2 = [
          'Bank Asya 1. Lig',
          'Bank Asya 1. Lig', 
          'Bank Asya 1. Lig',
          'Bank Asya 1. Lig',
          'PTT 1. Lig',
          'PTT 1. Lig',
          'PTT 1. Lig'
        ]
```

Сколько мучался, получается только так:

```
list2 = [
          'Bank Asya',
          'Bank Asya', 
          'Bank Asya',
          'Bank Asya',
          'PTT',
          'PTT',
          'PTT'
        ]
```

вот мой код:

```
list1 = [
          Bank Asya 1. Lig 2004/2005,
          Bank Asya 1. Lig 2006/2007, 
          Bank Asya 1. Lig 2008,
          Bank Asya 1. Lig 2009,
          PTT 1. Lig 2012/2013,
          PTT 1. Lig 2014,
          PTT 1. Lig 2015
        ]

list2 = []

for i in list1:
    ints  = re.search(r'\w+\D+', i)
    list2.append(ints.group(0))

print(list2)

# текущие результаты:    
# ['Bank Asya ', 'Bank Asya ', 'Bank Asya ', 'Bank Asya ', 'PTT ', 'PTT ', 'PTT ']

# желаемые результаты:
# ['Bank Asya 1. Lig', 'Bank Asya 1. Lig', 'Bank Asya 1. Lig', 'Bank Asya 1. Lig', 'PTT 1. Lig', 'PTT 1. Lig', 'PTT 1. Lig']
```

Comment: А если пойти другим путем...убрать с конца до первого пробела? Удовлетворит условиям?

Comment: Если строки всегда в таком формате, регулярки не нужны, используйте `list2.append(i.rsplit(' ', 1)[0])`

Comment: См. https://ideone.com/2dNVPw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://ideone.com/xMYJxK

```
import re

strs = [
  'Bank Asya 1. Lig 2004/2005',
  'Bank Asya 1. Lig 2006/2007', 
  'Bank Asya 1. Lig 2008',
  'Bank Asya 1. Lig 2009',
  'PTT 1. Lig 2012/2013',
  'PTT 1. Lig 2014',
  'PTT 1. Lig 2015'
]

print('\n'.join([re.sub('\s*\d{4}(/\d{4})?$', '', s) for s in strs]))
```